# ADF Copy Data to SFTP but don't try to delete the file first

Tags: azure-data-factory, sftp

I have a Copy Data transformation with my source as a SQL Server query and the sink is a CSV file on an SFTP server.

It's failing on the upload because it's trying to delete the file before it uploads.  I've established that I don't have delete permissions on the SFTP, and will not be granted them.

I can't figure out how to tell this action to ignore what's there and just upload.  Am I missing something, or are there any workarounds?  Thanks!  Snippets from the log are below, if that helps illustrate my post.

```
TraceComponentId: DataTranferCommon
TraceMessageId: ExecuteSftpCommand
@logId: Information
jobId: d15b0f79-0a45-4901-38b9-e8f5c7ed4183
activityId: b848942b-71bc-494b-8b4e-7b01ddf4c00e
eventId: ExecuteSftpCommand
message: *Start to delete file '/upload/MyFile.txt'.* CommandTimeout=01:00:00
```

---

```
TraceComponentId: TransferClientLibrary
TraceMessageId: ExecuteSftpCommandFailed
@logId: Error
FunctionName: DeleteFile
jobId: d15b0f79-0a45-4901-38b9-e8f5c7ed4183
activityId: b848942b-71bc-494b-8b4e-7b01ddf4c00e
eventId: ExecuteSftpCommandFailed
message: DeleteFile Failed: Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,
Message= Permission denied to access '/upload/MyFile.txt'.,
Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.SftpConnector,StackTrace=   
    at Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.SftpConnector.SftpFileSystem.WrapCommonSftpException(Exception ex, String filePath)
       at Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.SftpConnector.SftpFileSystem.WrapSftpException(String operation, Exception ex, String methodName, 
    String filePath)
    at Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.SftpConnector.SftpFileSystem.DeleteFile(String fullPath, Boolean throwExceptionForNotExistFile)
       at Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.SftpConnector.SftpFileSystem.OpenWriteStream(String absolutePath),
        ''Type=Renci.SshNet.Common.SftpPermissionDeniedException,Message=Permission denied. ,Source=Renci.SshNet,StackTrace=
       at Renci.SshNet.Sftp.SftpSession.RequestRemove(String path)
       at Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.SftpConnector.SftpFileSystem.c__DisplayClass42_0.b__0()
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

Source:
[image]

Sink:
[image]

Sink Detail:

[image]

Comment: can you provide images of your copy data source and sink

Answer (score 0):

When you use the Copy Data activity to copy data to the same file on an SFTP server, the Copy activity will internally delete the existing file and create a new file with the same name. This is the default behavior of the Copy activity when copying data to a file-based sink like FTP, ADLS.

Thus, it is necessary to have delete permission. If you don't have the necessary permissions to delete files on the SFTP server, you can use a different file name for each upload to avoid this issue. You can use a dynamic file name that includes a timestamp or a unique identifier to ensure that each file has a different name